# Different outputs in IDLE and IPython console in Spyder IDE. Possible reasons

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder

A particular function/command of mine has started behaving strangely.
[Remove items from a nested list based on comparing values obtained from another nested list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52853641/remove-items-from-a-nested-list-based-on-comparing-values-obtained-from-another)

```
a = [[1,2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[5],[1,2,3,6,7,8,9]]
b = [[1,4],[6,9]]
print ([[i for i in s if not any(l <= i <= h for l, h in b)] for s in a])
```

Expected Output :

```
[[5], [5], [5], []]
```

Output in IDLE and codeskulptor (https://py3.codeskulptor.org/) :

```
[[5], [5], [5], []]
```

Output in Spyder IDE (in the Ipython console) is

```
[[], [], [], []]
```

Code was working fine till EoD yesterday. I started my laptop again today and started having this discrepancy. My python installation is via Anaconda. Python version 3.6.6 (shown in both IDLE and Spyder) Spyder version is 3.3.1

I have tried restarting the laptop a couple of times as a last resort but can't seem to find the reason for this discrepancy

Comment: Restart the IPython kernel. Click in the IPython console and press `ctrl` + `.`

Comment: there must be a difference in your whole code somewhere else.

Comment: @roganjosh Tried it. Doesnt solve the problem.

Comment: Hmm, it's working fine for me in Spyder 3.2.4. I cannot replicate at all. You may need to raise it on their github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) I can reproduce the output you're seeing in Spyder if previous to your code I run

```
from numpy import any
```

Since you claim that you're getting the same result after a kernel restart, that means you have activated the option present in

`Tools > Preferences > IPython console > Graphics > Automatically load Pylab and NumPy modules`

So please deactivate that option to get the expected output with the builtin `any`.

Comment: Thanks, this works, but how do I ensure that this problem does not occur in the future. Will the command `import numpy as np` in my code continue to cause this problem ? I don't remember making any changes which caused this problem in the first place.

Comment: `import numpy as np` doesn't have this problem. The thing is the option I mentioned above imports the whole numpy directly into the console, i.e. it's equivalent to `from numpy import *` and that's why it's deactivated by default.